Strategy-proofness of a modified serial dictatorship algorithm
I am working on a practical problem and I have come up with an algorithm for that. I think this is strategy proof (I will outline my proof below) but I want to be sure.
There are, say $N$ agents who are to be allotted in $k$ groups. Each group can have a maximum of $n$ agents and each agent must be in exactly $g$ groups. Suppose there are enough seats for everyone ($Ng < nk$). Suppose there are no issues of group complementarities etc. Each agent has a complete and transitive ranking of groups they want to be in by preference.
The following is the algorithm:

An agent is chosen at random with uniform probability
If she is currently in less than $g$ groups, she is allotted to her highest ranked group excluding groups that already have $n$ members and groups she is already in. Otherwise, we skip her

Both the steps are repeated in order until all the agents are in exactly $k$ groups.
This is ex-ante fair because everybody has the same chance of being picked at any step. I think this is better ex-post than the usual serial dictatorship algorithm because there, those who are by chance picked earlier would have all the highly preferred groups, while those picked later would have all the bad ones (for example, if the preferences are highly positively correlated). But in this modified algorithm, there is re-shuffling after every single assignment of agent to group, bypassing that problem.
But my main concern is strategy-proofness. I think the modified algorithm is strategy-proof because of this:
Suppose everybody is reporting their preferences honestly. Take any agent $i$, whose true ranking is $x \succ y$. Their chance of selection is independent of what preferences they (or others) report. Once they are picked by chance, the group they have reported as more preferred will be allotted to them first and only when the agent is picked by chance again, will the next highest reportedly preferred group will be assigned.
Therefore, if the agent reports $x \succ y$, they are more likely to get $x$ than $y$ compared to when they report $y \succ x$. Since this is true for all pairs of groups, the agent is more likely to get more (truly) preferred groups than they will by misreporting.
Is the reasoning right? Are there any loopholes? Can someone give me a formal proof?
